# Is it possible to send email on behalf of another user?

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

We have two salesforce users A and B with different profiles.

B would like to send an email to our customer record in Salesforce but would like the email to be generated as if sent from A.

Is this possible ?

I looked into `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` and found out that while we can set the Bcc/CC addresses, there is no for me to set the "from address".

Can someone let me know their ideas on this ?

Thanks !

Comment: This user A context, how is it identified? Will it vary on email by email basis or will remain same for all others emails as well?

Comment: Tx for the response..User A will vary on email by email basis

Comment: Another question, will the receivers be replying back to email received? Or just the User name A should appear as "Sender Name" and email address doesn't matter.

Comment: Our customers will respond to the emails sent to them so the email address should contain A's address...I know its asking a lot :(...Just wanna check whether it is at all possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it isn't currently possible. You could use [`setSenderDisplayName(String displayName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_Messaging_Email_setSenderDisplayName) to change the from Name, but it won't change to reply email address.

The alternative is to use an [OrgWideEmailAddress](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=orgwide_email.htm&language=en_US&type=0), which will also change the sending Email Address in addition to the Display Name.

Crazy idea, make Organization-Wide Email Addresses for all the users who need to appear in the from address and put them in the same profile as the actual sender. Then associate the ID with the user and set it via `setOrgWideEmailAddressId`. Will need some config, but it should work.